# Find files and delete characters in the filenames

Tags: sed, find

So I have a directory called `testdir` and I want to delete the underscores in the filenames from the files in that directory.

I tried to use this command

`find testdir -type f -exec ls {} \; | sed 's/_*//'`

It will output the filenames without the underscores but it won't delete the underscores permanently. Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looping through the files in your dir, use a simple loop:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   echo mv "$file" "${file//_/}"         #once you are sure it works, remove the echo!
done < <(find -type f -name "*_*")
```

This will feed the `while` loop with the output of the `find` command. Then, uses `${var//_/}` to remove all `_` in the name.

---

Why wasn't your approach working?

Because you are saying

```
find ... -exec ls {} \; | sed '...'
```

That is, you are finding something and then changing the output with `sed`. That is, nothing is done to the file itself.

Comment: No but the name of the files are not changed if you cd testdir again, thanks tho!

Comment: @DriesCoppens not sure what you mean and what you tried. As you see in my answer, you need to remove the `echo` once you see it works as intended.

Comment: Yes I see, but with my method it didn't change :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you
find testdir -type f | rename 's/_//'

Regards